# need to get selected value into json object

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, vue.js

i need to get my selected dropdown value into my json object. i tried this code but not showing my selected value.

```
<select class="form-control select2 dynamic" style="width: 100%;" 
name="customer" id="customer" v-model="sale.customer">
<option disabled value="">Please Select One</option>
<option :value="users.name" v-for="user in users">{{ user.name }}</option>
</select>
```

i want to get this selected value into this json object.

```
sale: 
{
  customer: '',
}
```

and this array i used to get all users from user table.

```
users: [],
```

i want to get this selected value into customer object. can any one know how to fix this error in vuejs

Comment: Is `sale` reactive? i.e. is it defined as part of the component's `data` object?

Comment: @StephenThomas Thomas yes. it's a part of data object